# Trouble in Accepting the Dialog Box using Playwright Python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, playwright

[image]

Hoe can I accept the dialog using python playwright. For your kind information I have already tried this code but it doesn't seems to work for me. Any other solution other than that will be appreciable. Thanks

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

def handle_dialog(dialog):
    print(dialog.message)
    dialog.dismiss()

def run(playwright):
    chromium = playwright.chromium
    browser = chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.on("dialog", handle_dialog)
    page.evaluate("alert('1')")
    browser.close()

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    run(playwright)
```

Comment: This isn't a dialog, it's a browser notification. Please clarify ["doesn't work"](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/).

Comment: it means that dialog box code not working for this dialog, you told me that this is not a dialog so how can I click on accept button using playwright python